# Are these two implementations of safe ERC-20 equivalent?

Tags: erc-20, returndata

These implementations from Uniswap and Compound seem both to have been written to account for the [missing return value bug](https://medium.com/coinmonks/missing-return-value-bug-at-least-130-tokens-affected-d67bf08521ca) - an issue with some ERC20 token contracts that don't return a boolean when `transfer` or `transferFrom` is called.

From Uniswap's [TransferHelper.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-lib/blob/master/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol)

```
function safeTransfer(address token, address to, uint value) internal {
  // bytes4(keccak256(bytes('transfer(address,uint256)')));
  (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(0xa9059cbb, to, value));
  require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FAILED');
}
```

From Compound's [Erc20.sol](https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/blob/cce8c8836d21ac307df918a4ca46f0b83dbe2757/contracts/CErc20.sol):

```
function doTransferOut(address payable to, uint amount) internal {
    EIP20NonStandardInterface token = EIP20NonStandardInterface(underlying);
    token.transfer(to, amount);

    bool success;
    assembly {
        switch returndatasize()
            case 0 {                      // This is a non-standard ERC-20
                success := not(0)          // set success to true
            }
            case 32 {                     // This is a complaint ERC-20
                returndatacopy(0, 0, 32)
                success := mload(0)        // Set `success = returndata` of external call
            }
            default {                     // This is an excessively non-compliant ERC-20, revert.
                revert(0, 0)
            }
    }
    require(success, "TOKEN_TRANSFER_OUT_FAILED");
}
```

The question: are they equivalent?

Comment: The first one compiles only from solc 0.5 onward. If you're on that version, then you may as well use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent.

The first will allow to return more than 32 bytes of data. The second one will revert in that case.

There are also other side effects like the first one allocates memory for the returned data and the second doesn't allocate new memory it uses the 0 address.